# How to Force Div on top to be the Only thing Scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a div called "`full-sidebar`" that's on top of another div called "`page`".

When the `full-sidebar` div has a z-index of 100, it's on top of the `page` div. When the `full-sidebar` is on the top, it's still scrollable from the `page` div below it is very long.

How would I set up css so that it only cares if the top div is scrollable and not the divs behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the rule :

```css
* {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then enable it to your `full-sidebar` with :

```css
#full-sidebar {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

So that only the `full-sidebar` will be scrollable